# Google Map JS API does not load correctly unless refreshed in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have an app testing website as listed below:

[Testing Site](https://wii.elementmedia.design/vawe-app/www/index.html)

And the problem I am having is if you click "Map" at the bottom, when the page loads the zoom on the map is not correct, and it does not seem to be loading roads or anything else. If I refresh the anchor tag link #map, then the page loads fine with the map showing the right info. What could be causing this to happen?

Thanks for anyone's help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question currently lacks the information necessary to generate good answers. Please provide some example code showing the problem, not just a link to the site. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're calling the following:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

before you source:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBpoSVdtZlPqe8aHatLN8JdUrtpP6gh2D4&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Move the google API src call to your first script source.

**-------EDIT-------**

I just noticed that you're using a callback in the google maps src call. This changes things a little bit.

Because of this you're going to want to source Google Maps last.

Be sure to move your `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);` call into your initialize function.

I've created a little JSFiddle here for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/4v4rmndo/

```
<script>

    var initMap = function() {
    alert('init Map!')
  }

  var initialize = function() {
    alert('Initialize!!!');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
  }

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Comment: I just moved it as you said and it still isn't working on the first load

Answer (score 0):

You have code that's trying to execute before the google script has loaded, resulting in a console error (always a good idea to look in the console when something isn't working):

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);`

Place your reference to the google script above this, or put code like this inside a ready handler to ensure that it's not executed until the DOM has been loaded along with any script references.